# Get MAC address of host inside a docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker, c++11

I'm looking for an efficient way to get the MAC address of host inside a docker container. The docker container will not run with host network enabled and I don't want to supply the MAC address as an ENV variable. There would be a program ( preferably C++ or Python code ) that runs inside the docker container. The program would write the MAC address to a file. The MAC address will be the true MAC address of the host's network device. The docker will have a Ubuntu operating system. Any ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$') > /path/you/choose/host_mac_address
```

When running you docker run

```
    docker run -v /path/you/choose:/app container
```

Inside your app just need to open the file located /app/host_mac_address

Make all of this better when you got the idea

*All of this will be better using an ENV variable (but you dont want this solution)*

Comment: This will give the MAC address for sure. Thanks, but here we are supplying the MAC address externally from the host. Is it possible to do it completely internal? Inside the container itself, without supplying anything from host.

Comment: As I kow the all point of a container is to isolated the process, to avoir getting the host(parent) information.

crazy idea try to share `-v /sys/class/net/eth0/address:/network` then `cat /network`

didn't try but maybe work. let me know